# Tab delimited data to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to wrangle some tab delimited data into a better format that I can work with. JSON would be just great.

Data example is here: http://www.nlaa.ca/results/rr/2013/20130728tely10results.php

I've downloaded all the data and have each year in it's own text file. From there, I'm globbing them and running them into a foreach and reading through them line by line. Like so:

```
// Grab all the .txt files
foreach (glob('src-data/*.txt') as $filename ) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
    if ( $handle ) {
        // run line by line through the files
        while (( $line = fgets($handle) ) !== false) {
            // grab the fields 
            $clean = preg_split("/ +/", $line);
```

From here, I want to put all the lines in a giant associative array:

```
            // All the fields
            $position = $clean[1];
            $name = $clean[3] . " " . $clean[4];
            $time = $clean[5];
            $class = $clean[6];
            $class_place = $clean[7];


            $runners['position'] = $position;
            $runners['name'] = $name;
            $runners['time'] = $time;
            $runners['class'] = $class;
            $runners['class place'] = $class_place;
```

This sorta works, but it only creates one array for each of the .txt files I have.

When I do `print_r($runners);` I get two arrays — one for each of the two sample .txt files I have in that directory.

I want to push each new line to my `$runners[]` array as I loop over it.

My ultimate goal here is to create a big json file that I can use with Js down the road. I think just running `json_encode($runners)` will work if I can get `$runners` working, but appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks!

Here's the full code I'm using, just to be sure:

```
<?php


$runners = [];

// Grab all the .txt files
foreach (glob('src-data/*.txt') as $filename ) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');

    if ( $handle ) {
        // run line by line through the files
        while (( $line = fgets($handle) ) !== false) {
            // grab the fields 
            $clean = preg_split("/ +/", $line);

            // All the fields
            $position = $clean[1];
            $name = $clean[3] . " " . $clean[4];
            $time = $clean[5];
            $class = $clean[6];
            $class_place = $clean[7];


            $runners['position'] = $position;
            $runners['name'] = $name;
            $runners['time'] = $time;
            $runners['class'] = $class;
            $runners['class place'] = $class_place;

            $runners[] = $clean;


        }
        print_r($runners);

        // write to json file
        $jsonwrite = fopen('runners.json', 'w');
        fwrite($jsonwrite, json_encode($runners));
        fclose($jsonwrite);

        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        echo "Error opening file";
    }
}



?>
```

Comment: why not use fgetcsv() instead of manually parsing the raw data line? you specific custom separators quite easily.

Comment: Thanks Marc — I gave this a quick try but didn't seem to get far. All the columns have different numbers of spaces between them. Maybe fgetcsv() can handle that somehow.  I shall google! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$runners['position'] = $position;
$runners['name'] = $name;
$runners['time'] = $time;
$runners['class'] = $class;
$runners['class place'] = $class_place;

$runners[] = $clean;
```

With:

```
$runners[] = [
    'position' => $position,
    'name' => $name,
    'time' => $time,
    'class' => $class,
    'class_place' => $class_place
];
```

And you'll get something like (dummy data):

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'position' => 1,
        'name' => 'Hans Muster',
        'time' => '05:18',
        'class' => '1A',
        'class_place' => '2'
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'position' => 4,
        'name' => 'Franz Muster',
        'time' => '08:12',
        'class' => '1A',
        'class_place' => '7'
    )
)
```

Comment: would not have gotten that for sure!   Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're not "pushing" onto an array at all. You just have an array that you continually overwrite some member values. You should have something more like:

```
$arr = array();
foreach(... list of files ...) {
     $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
     while ($row = fgetcsv($fh, .... options ...)) {
        ... process $row ...
        $arr[] = $row;
     }
     fclose($fh);
}
```

Note the `[]`  - that is the "push" operation.

Comment: Quite right.  Just looked up what 'push' actually means.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is to kindly solve everyone's problem and it should be noted how easy it is

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("file.json"));
...
file_put_contents("file.json",json_encode($json,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Yes after years of searching.:D

You're welcome!
Make sure the file is writable!